# text entry settings won't work after suspend

Tags: unity, 18.04

I have ubuntu 18.04 working in unity-protocol.
Whenever I turn off my computer or suspend it, the key combination I chose for "switching to next source" of language doesn't work, and I need to set it again in the text entry settings (although the combination is still written there).

On 16.04 I didn't have this problem, nor on the 18.04 ubuntu-protocol